# Combining setTimeout with setInterval

Tags: javascript

I would like to use polling to try and grab data from a backend service.  If the data does not appear after x seconds, I would like to cancel out and log an error to the console.

Is there an easy way to do this? I'd assume it's something close to the code below

Ex:

```
// Keep polling for something every 2.5 seconds
const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
  const isFound = doSomePollingQuery();
  if (isFound) {
    window.clearInterval(intervalId);
  }
}, 2500);

// If the polling interval hasn't been found by 17 seconds, 
// cancel it and output a message
setTimeout(() => {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
  console.log("Not found in time"); // Where should this be 
                                    // moved to as it doesn't belong here?
}, 17000);
```

Comment: Why does the console not belong there?

Comment: Because it will run regardless of success

Comment: So you cancel the timeout in the interval

Comment: Then also cancel the setTimeout when ur Polling was successful?!?

Comment: I don't understand either of your comments, sorry

Comment: You clear the interval. So clear the timeout. It is the same thing. Store the timeout id. Clear it.

Comment: I still don't see how to do it. code example please?

Comment: `window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);` and `const timeoutId = window.setTimeout(...)`

Comment: I don't see how that ties in with the console.log and how that gets placed. Please use my example code to show me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Keep polling for something every 2.5 seconds
const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
  const isFound = doSomePollingQuery();
  if (isFound) {
    console.log("Found in time")
    window.clearInterval(intervalId);
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  }
}, 2500);

// If the polling interval hasn't been found by 17 seconds, 
// cancel it and output a message
const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
  console.log("Not found in time"); // Where should this be 
                                    // moved to as it doesn't belong here?
}, 17000);
```

Comment: Seems to be working, thanks!  I do get compiler errors about using timeoutId before it was defined though, which I have to explicitly ignore